# Changing C# .dll references from absolute to relative

Tags: c#, dll, reference, relative-path, absolute-path

I have compiled my project and some of my project's added .dlls have absolute references.  When I try to run my project on another machine, it looks for the .dlls from the original project path.

How can I make the project look for the .dlls using a relative path?

Comment: AFAIK, when you specify an absolute path to the dll, it gets translated to a relative path in the project file, so on other machines the relative path is used...

Comment: Avoid referencing assemblies that are stored on another drive.

Answer (score 19):

Edit the `.csproj` file and change the `<HintPath>` elements from absolute paths to relative paths.

Comment: When I was adding DLL references I noticed it automatically used relative paths. In what instances would Visual Studio have used absolute paths?

Comment: It uses absolute paths when the assembly you are referencing is above the root of the project.

Comment: I just checked and **even if** the assembly is above the root of the project, VS 2010  adds relative paths automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You may also write your handler for resolving assemblies. In the simplest form it may look like this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolveHandler;
..
static Assembly AssemblyResolveHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
  string assemblyPath = "yourpath";
  return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath + args.Name);
}
```

Another option is adding entry in App.config:

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="yourpath"/>
     </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```